# Telegram Python bot to upload media as video

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I've been trying to make a Python-based Telegram bot that can read RSS feed and upload videos.

This is the code and it is working:

https://pastecode.io/s/jhydzq2w

However, bot is currently uploading videos as a attachment/file. How can modify the bot and upload it as a video (which has thumbnail)?

Comment: You can use [send_video](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/send_video)

Comment: The [telebot library](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/#writing-your-first-bot) is capable of doing so. You would just set the content type to video .... @bot.message_handler(content_types=['video'])

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Can you point out the line I need modify? Thanks.

Comment: From what I can make of the code, I'd say you'd replace line 94 with `cient.send_video(message.chat.id, filepath)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Client.send_video() methond

here is docs:
https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/send_video

replace sent_files.extend with Client.send_video().

Comment: I added it, but bot seems to be crashing: https://i.imgur.com/fKymrwb.png

Comment: @Maya, try client, not Client.